# xampp with openssl 1.0.0 or higher

Tags: xampp

I need a xampp with openssl 1.0.0 or higher with php 5.4 and apache 2.4+ which can run on windows server 2003.

Xampp 1.8.3 is there but it doesn't work on windows server 2003.

Can you please suggest me any version??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Xampp` works in `server 2003`, the issue you are facing is because Windows Server 2003 is a server operating system which has a per-installed `IIS server` which runs using the same port. I recommend you to shutdown the IIS services then try restarting xampp to make it work. you can reach the services console by services.msc